# Windows shows wrong time after dualboot

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I have windows and kubuntu dualboot, when i boot windows after kubuntu, windows shows wrong time. How can i fix this? I use refind for dualboot, my motherboard is GA-970A-DS3P

Comment: This question is not about programming, so it's off-topic here. (Hint: Google for "configure system clock as UTC")

Comment: Maybe topic for https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in terminal of kubuntu

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

By default, Linux assumes that the time stored in the hardware clock is in UTC, not the local time. On the other hand, Windows thinks that the time stored on the hardware clock is local time. That’s where the trouble starts.

https://itsfoss.com/wrong-time-dual-boot/